"Truth is a product of two opposing sets of truths", why not?
How would one go about arguing that the definition of truth as "truth is a product of two opposing sets of truths" (H) is wrong?
For the argument's sake, let's imagine a website where it is possible to post different propositions and the community curates two lists of arguments: Yes and No. On this website, we could post a proposition such as "Something is true because it has not yet been proved false" (A). This proposition on the "No" side would have the logical fallacy argument, whilst on the "Yes" side there could be arguments that mention various situations in science or law where it is practical to assume this proposition as being true e.g. not guilty until proven wrong.
We could re-form all of the arguments on both the Yes and No sides of (A) into propositions of their own that have both Yes/No sides of the argument.
Eventually, we could also post (H) with an argument (A) on the Yes side. But what could then be possible to post on the No side in order to argue against (H)?
Just to clarify, in case this comes up, product in this case is a truth value your consciousness converges too, but it could be many other things: a peace treaty, a verdict by a judge, a knockout in a fight.

Similar to "likes" of Facebook? More the likes,  more truth?

@MauroALLEGRANZA In this version there are no likes. Arguments are simply presented in a text form. In this thought experiment, you would load up the arguments of both sides, and converge somewhere between true and false. The truth value here is subjective, since it would depend on one's biases. The biases themselves are products of the same process.

@MauroALLEGRANZA the process here is similar to listening a debated between two presidential candidates, and forming one's opinion. Hope this helps to clarify.

Ok, debate is fundamental. There is also Dialogical Logic.

Offering situations where it is practical to accept a proposition does not even attempt to argue for "true because it has not yet been proven false". "Could be this, could be that" does not add clarity to what is being asked either. Funnily enough, when I saw (H) I initially thought that you were ascribing this to Hegel. And it is vaguely reminiscent of his dialectic, namely sublation of opposites that negates but preserves, "the result is conceived as it is in truth". Why don't you settle on what "product" does mean for the purposes of this question, SE is not for imitating debates.

@Conifold can you clarify your first sentence, are you not happy with the argument from practicality that argues for the proposition "Something is true because it has not yet been proved false" being true? Or are you not happy that the argument "Something is true because it has not yet been proved false" is used to argue for (H) being true?

The argument is a side issue to fixing the question. But accepting something as practical is neither here nor there as far as its truth is concerned. So it is beside the point of the argued proposition.

@Conifold so if I understand right, you are saying that (A) is a weak argument for the truth of (H) since just because it is practical to assume that something is true, and there are propositions considered to be true just because there are no evidence of being otherwise, it does not make (H) true?

(A) is not an argument for truth of (H) at all because it misreads what (H) is saying. If one wishes to argue that "truth is what works" they should argue that "what works" defines the truth generally instead of presenting situations where it is practical to act as if something was true. That it is practical to act as if red means danger has no bearing on the meaning of "danger".

@Conifold after reading your argument, I genuinely agree that it is true that (A) is not an argument for truth of (H), before I thought otherwise. It seems like we have found truth here.

@Conifold but then again, given this conversation, what exactly does (A) fail to prove here? I have intentionally picked something weak for (A), its function was to act as an invitation to the game that is described by (H). It is a pawn sacrifice. On its face value throwing (A) as a card is a mistake, but from the perspective of the whole game it is not.

To be fair, I am a bit on the face opening with the argument from ignorance here, since it is one of those 2000 IQ moves. A stronger argument would work here too, but it just seems superfluous and less diabolical.
